# Can I remove crypto-browserify from reactjs project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a reactjs project built in `"react": "^16.13.1"` version and I noticed that some node dependencies are `crypto-browserify` which contains dependencies like md5.js . I tried updating the project to react version `17.0.2` but the dependencies still there. Is this library really needed? I read somewhere that it is not, and its been included because somehwere in the code might be using the `crypto` class, which is not my case.

PD: I also tried updating react-scripts to 5.0.0, manually (for some reason when installing the latst version it installs version 4) and this make crypto-browserify to disappear from `package-lock.json` but it also generates some other errors like sourcemap warnings.

So, is there any save way to remove that dependency?

Comment: If you run `npm ls --all` you should be able to find which package depends on `crypto-browserify`. If there are none, `npm prune` (you can run `npm prune --dry-run` to test it first) should remove it. If you use `package-lock.json`, NPM should do this automatically for you.